# How do I stop my visualforce page from creating another development mode bar?

Tags: visualforce

When I click on a link on my visual force page to go to another visualforce page, it creates another development window. How do I stop this from happening?

[image: How do I stop this from happening?]

Comment: looks like you are using VF page inside VF page ? If yes I suggest disable the development mode.

Comment: this is standard behavior of Salesforce where you can check code of your new visualforce page. You can't override this behavior. You can only disable the development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parameter `core.apexpages.devmode.url=0` will disable development mode

Try this when calling the `Other` VisualForce page:

```
/apex/OtherPage?core.apexpages.devmode.url=0
```

Comment: This is good to know. Worked like a charm.